# Recargar un iframe desde otro iframe

Tags: botón, iframe

Tengo dos iframes lo que requiero es que desde el iframe uno pueda recargar mi iframe dos

```
<iframe id="frame1" src="http://localhost/boleto2/prueba-productos-ifram/" height="1000" width="700" title="Iframe Example"></iframe>    
 <iframe id="frame2" src="http://localhost/boleto2/prueba-ifram/" height="1000" width="700" title="Iframe Example"></iframe>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor agrega el código de lo que has intentado. Te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer [ask]

Comment: Hols Cesar, bienvenido, además de mostrar lo que has intentado, te sugiero que trates de ser más claro en la explicación de lo que necesitas, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo logre solucionar  ese es el codigo para quien guste

```html
function cargar_iframe(pag){

//document.getElementById('iframe1').src=pag+".html";
window.parent.document.getElementById('iframe1').contentWindow.location.reload();

}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<iframe  width="800px" height="600px" id="iframe1" src="http://localhost/boleto2/"></iframe>
  



function cargar_iframe2(pag){

//document.getElementById('iframe2').src=pag+".html";

window.parent.document.getElementById('iframe2').contentWindow.location.reload();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<iframe  width="800px" height="600px" id="iframe2" src="http://localhost/boleto2/pago-en-linea/"></iframe>
  
<p>
<input type="button"  onclick="cargar_iframe('pagina1')" value="Pagina 1">
```